# Trigger on MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a trigger in MySQL using phpMyAdmin, but I'm getting and error and I can't detect the mistake. The main idea its to create a row in the tables *stuff* and *config* when a new user is insered.

**The code:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_stuff_and_config 
AFTER INSERT ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into stuff(user_id) values (NEW.user_id);     
    insert into config(user_id) values(NEW.user_id);
END;
```

**The error:**

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

I've checked the MySQL doc but I see like I'm doing it well...

I've tried too: `INSERT INTO stuff SET user_id = NEW.user_id;`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution is to add delimiters...

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER create_stuff_and_config 
AFTER INSERT ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into stuff(user_id) values (NEW.user_id);     
    insert into config(user_id) values(NEW.user_id);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```